# Having difficulty understanding the genere of Trap House

Tags: genre, electronic-music

Can someone please describe to me what, exactly, is trap house? Examples welcomed!!

Answer (score 1):

**Trap House Genre:**

**Trap music is defined by its ominous, bleak and gritty lyrical content which varies widely according to artist.**

*Typical lyrical themes portrayed include observations of hardship in the "trap", street life, poverty, violence and harsh experiences in urban surroundings.*

*Trap music incorporates an extensive use of multi-layered hard-lined and melodic synthesizers; crisp, grimy and rhythmic snares; deep 808 sub-bass kick drums or heavy sub-bass lines; double-time, triple-time and similarly divided hi-hats; and a cinematic and symphonic utilization of string, brass and keyboard instruments **creating an overall dark, harsh, grim and bleak atmosphere for the listener.***

**These primary characteristics would go on to be the signature sound of trap music originating from producer Shawty Redd. The tempo of a typical trap beat is around 140 BPM.**

[Check this for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music)